# How to remove all newlines from a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, text-editing, newlines

I have the command `cat file.txt | gawk '{print $2}' > test` which displays:

```
1
1
0
0
1
1
```

Afterwards:

```
vi test
:%s/\n//
```

Which outputs: `110011`

My question is I don't know how I could incorporate this last step with pipes.

Update: Might be with `sed`. I tried to use `sed 's/\n//'` but still doesn't work (it changes nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete bytes in the file `test` just use [`tr`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html). This will save the output in `test2`

```
<test tr -d '\n' >test2
```

Instead of `cat` and piping like that you should redirect directly

You can use [`awk`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html) but it also receives a file name so no need to pipe the output to it like in your answer, and you also don't actually need 2 steps like that. Just set the [output record separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html) which is a new line by default to an empty string. This will print the second field from the original file directly into the output file

```
awk -v ORS='' '{ print $2 }' file.txt >test
# or
awk -v ORS='' '{ print $2 }' <file.txt >test
```

Alternative the variable can be set like this

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS="" } { print $2 }' file.txt >test
```

You might want to add `END { print "\n" }` to print a newline at the end

[Demo on online bash](https://onlinegdb.com/iC1fnkcnk)

Comment: The command `<test tr -d '\n' >test2` works just fine, thanks for that :) But I don't know why the awk commands don't work for me. When I do a `cat test` after the awk commands, I get no output.

Comment: remember that command runs with the original `file.txt`, not the test. That's why I said you need only 1 step, no need to go through the intermediate `test` file

Comment: @phyclv You're right! Thank you very much for the demo as well :]

Answer (score 2):

You would need another gawk that substitute newlines to "":

```
cat file.txt | gawk '{print $2}' | gawk '{printf "%s",$0} END {print ""}'
```

Source: [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/391360/remove-line-break-using-awk?newreg=17970ac1803b4c72ab5b10c9336fb6b7) (serverfault.com)

Even simpler:

```
cat test | awk '{printf $2} END {print ""}'
```

And finally:

```
cat test | gawk '{printf $2}'
```

*(Using cygwin64 terminal)*

Comment: And now really final: `gawk '{printf $2}' test`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:

```
gawk '{print $2}' file.txt | paste -d'\0' -s
```

`-s` does a serial `paste`
`-d '\0'` pastes without a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family of programming languages. In particular, Raku offers high-level Unicode support built-in, no external libraries required:*

```perl
~$ cat test | raku -e 'lines.join.put;' 

#OR

~$ cat test | raku -ne '.print;'
```

Sample Input:

```
1
1
0
0
1
1
```

Sample Output:

```
110011
```

https://raku.org